# Browse and modify files in the file system of 'Visual Studio Emulator for Android'

Tags: android, xamarin

How can i browse the file system on my 'Visual Studio Emulator for Android' from my PC?

I'm running VS 15.9.4 with Xamarin. I'm looking for a way to inspect and update files on the emulator in a similar way i do with a file manager on a real android device, but directly from my PC.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use the Android Device Monitor that is packaged as part of the Android SDK.  The easiest way to access this from Visual Studio for Windows is to click on `Tools->Android->Android Device Monitor...`.  This will open the Android Device Monitor packaged with the Android SDK.  When it opens, you can click select your emulator under the "Devices" tab.  Then click on the "File Explorer" tab so see files in the file system.

I don't think this is integrated into Visual Studio (like it is with Android Studio), but this is good way to browse the emulator file system and other useful things.

[image]